# Always show "label" in a self join

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is simple and complicated question at the same time. There is only two tables

1.Company Categories (with 2 levels, Main and Sub)

2.Link table (Company ID and Category ID)

The Company Categories have both Main Categories and Sub Categories in same table.

The problem is that the Main Category only shows up if there is a Sub Category.

In the code below both the Main Category and Sub Category shows up IF there is a Sub Category connected. a. is the Main Category and b. is the Sub Category.

```
SELECT a."COCAT_NAME" AS MAIN,b."COCAT_NAME" AS SUB
FROM cocat a, cocat b
LEFT JOIN cocatlnk ON "COCATLNK_CAT" = "COCAT_ID"
WHERE a."COCAT_NODE"='0' AND a."COCAT_ID"=b."COCAT_MAIN" AND "COCATLNK_CO"='[lv_ID]'
ORDER BY a."COCAT_NAME"
```

How do I do to always get the Main Categories even if there is no Sub Categories?

Comment: did you try a right join?

Comment: Yes, No difference. Also tried LEFT OUTER JOIN. No luck.

Comment: Proper table definitions would be so much better. Use what you get in `psql` with `\d tbl`. Plus, as always, your version of Postgres. And please table-qualify *all* columns in the query. Else we have no idea where they come from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion. I found a solution at last. Combination of self join and subquery. The outer query always produce "labels" regardless if there is any links:

```
SELECT "COCAT_NAME" AS MAIN,
(SELECT "COCAT_NAME"
FROM cocat sub
LEFT JOIN cocatlnk ON "COCATLNK_CAT" = sub."COCAT_ID"
WHERE "COCATLNK_CO"='[lv_CO]' AND sub."COCAT_MAIN"= main."COCAT_ID") AS SUB
FROM cocat main
WHERE "COCAT_NODE"='0'
ORDER BY MAIN
```

If you have a simpler solution, please enlighten me.

"I would advice to use unquoted, valid, lower-case identifiers to make your life easier."

I know that now, a bit too late :-)

Answer (score 1):

Stab in the dark, guessing the missing information:

```
SELECT m."COCAT_NAME" AS main, s."COCAT_NAME" AS sub
FROM   cocat m
LEFT   JOIN cocatlnk l ON l."COCAT_ID" = m."COCAT_ID"
LEFT   JOIN cocat s ON s."COCAT_ID" = l."COCATLNK_CAT"
                   AND s."COCAT_MAIN" =  m."COCAT_ID"   -- seems redundant?
WHERE  m."COCAT_NODE" = '0'
AND    ???."COCATLNK_CO" = '[lv_ID]'   -- replace ??? with actual table
ORDER  BY m."COCAT_NAME";
```

I would advice to use unquoted, valid, *lower-case* identifiers to make your life easier.